# Is the sum of rational exponentials a rational exponential?.

Tags: exponentiation, rational-numbers

Prove or disprove that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and $ \forall p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ there exists $c \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and  $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that:
$$
a^p+b^q=c^r
$$

Comment: Have you made any attempts on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}$ is of the shape $c^r$, where $c$ is a positive rational and $r=\frac{m}{n}$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers, with $n\gt 0$. Show by taking the $n$-th power of both sides that this implies that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Comment: Yes!! In the binomial formula for $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ there's always some $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right, in the expansion all terms are positive, so there cannot be cancellation.